# Converting Java date(milliseconds) to Javascript Date (ExtJs)

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, date-conversion

I have a date in milliseconds that I am receiving from Java server side, I want 
to convert it into javascript `Date` object:

```
long s = 1523357477; // Java end
var v= new Date(1523357477); //Javascript ExtJS end
```

But it gives:

> **Sun Jan 18 1970 20:39:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

It's wrong because in Extjs grid panel converts the same date to this:

> 10-04-2018 14:23

below is the code snippet of ExtJs grid columns, The main job is done by **Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer**

```
{
    headerId: 'column-creation-date',
    dataIndex: 'creationDate',
    text: 'Created at',
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer,
    width: 155,
    filter: true
}
```

Comment: your `milliseconds` is not corrected `1523357477`

Comment: but the same milliseconds are correctly formatted by ExtJS grid view

Comment: Please provide the ExtJS GRID code

Comment: Hey You are right, the millisecond is wrong, actually, ExtJS grid is multiplying this milliseconds by 1000 then converting to date object

Comment: So your "milliseconds" are in fact seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The given timestamp(millisecond)is wrong, this millisecond is stored in mongodb. ExtJs first multiply timestamp by 1000 then converts to date object

Comment: How are you reaching that conclusion? You haven't posted any relevant code.

Comment: After debugging a lot, I concluded this. I am posting the code of ExtJs grid